# I localized my app to Japan but I cannot see it

Tags: iphone, localization, itunes, app-store-connect

recently I uploaded my app internationally including Japan, France, China, etc using iTunes Connect.

I can see French version of my app at French Apple's App Store. However, I only appears in English at Japan & China's App Store. (I translated all the information in both languages just like in French)

What happened? What should I do to fix this?

Comment: you have checked French iTunes for this? you can change the itunes country from the bottom icon of iTunes.

Comment: That's what I did. I went to Japan and China App Store but its in English.

Comment: Please check you have added right localization in iTunes.

Comment: I just confirmed that there is nothing different between what I did for French and Japanese. Actually making multiple versions of localization is simple step as we know. What went wrong.......

Comment: Having the same problem; weirdly my translated description appears on the iTunes web preview, but not within the iTunes app, even when I switch the store country.

Answer (score 0):

Did you submit the extra paperwork that is necessary to sell apps in Japan? There is a special form you need. Without that your apps won't appear in Japan.

Comment: AFAIK those forms are so you don't get taxes withheld by the Japanese gov't, not for your app to appear in the Japan App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the Apple dev forums. Apparently changing the App Store country is not enough, you need to set your Mac's preferred language in System Preferences.

1. Close iTunes
2. Open System Preferences, go to Language & Text, then drag Japanese (or whatever) to the top of the list
3. Close System Preferences
4. Open iTunes, then change your App Store country to Japan (or whatever)
5. Your localized app name/description should appear correctly