# App in Simplified Chinese but appears in English in Chinese App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an strange problem with localizations for my app. It's translated into English, Chinese (Simplified), French, German, Italian, Portuguese, Russian and Spanish. Switching to different countries in App Store displays the correct translated description for the language of the country, except for China. Here are the screenshots for my localization stuff:

[image: Piano Chords and Scales, project settings]
[image: Piano Chords and Scales, metadata]
[image: Piano Chords and Scales, App Store]
[image: Piano Chords and Scales, language settings]

I did what someone suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7405304/845587), but I am still getting the English version for China App Store. Something I have missed, any suggestion?

**More info:** The iTunes Store Chinese link for this app appears in chinese, but clicking "View in iTunes" opens it in iTunes in english

http://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/piano-chords-scales/id500492595?mt=8